# How to make a runnable terminate early

Tags: java, runnable

I have a runnable, the code below, whenever it's called in 10 seconds it should do whatever.

```
CoresManager.slowExecutor.schedule(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (isAtWildSafe()) {
                                player.sm("This area is now safe for you.");
                                player.setCanPvp(false);
                                player.safeWait = false;
                                removeIcon();
                            }
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            Logger.handle(e);
                        }
                    }
                }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But, lets say 5 seconds has gone by, and I want to cancel the runnable before it can do its action. How would I achieve this without canceling all the active runnables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `schedule(...)` method should return a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object.  The `Future` API has a `cancel(...)` method.

So to achieve what you want to do: save the `Future` object somewhere and then call `cancel` on it after 5 seconds.  Note that it is OK to cancel a future that has already been run.

Comment: Can I get an example on how to set schedule to a Future object..?

Comment: Aren't you already doing that in the code in your question?  (But if not, try Googling for examples.)

Comment: Never mind, I honestly wasn't thinking properly when asking that. My bad.